# MongoDB Installation Error

Tags: windows, mongodb, installation

I am trying to install MongoDB. I have windows 7 and below is the configuration.

[image]

and I am getting the following error while installing

[image]

Can anyone tell how can I fix this error?

Comment: Make sure you are downloading a 32-bit installation for MongoDB. As of MongoDB 3.4, 32-bit releases are no longer supported so you will have to choose from "Previous Releases" in the [MongoDB Download Centre](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#previous). The MongoDB 3.2 production release series is the last to support 32-bit.

Comment: got it!!! thank you